# Python- how to convert lines in a .txt file to dictionary elements?

Tags: python, file, dictionary

Say I have a file "stuff.txt" that contains the following on separate lines: 
    q:5 
    r:2 
    s:7

I want to read each of these lines from the file, and convert them to dictionary elements, the letters being the keys and the numbers the values. 
So I would like to get
    y ={"q":5, "r":2, "s":7}

I've tried the following, but it just prints an empty dictionary "{}"

```
y = {} 
infile = open("stuff.txt", "r") 
z = infile.read() 
for line in z: 
    key, value = line.strip().split(':') 
    y[key].append(value) 
print(y) 
infile.close()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
d = {}
with open('text.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.strip().split(':')
        d[key] = int(value)
```

You are appending to `d[key]` as if it was a list. What you want is to just straight-up assign it like the above.

Also, using `with` to open the file is good practice, as it auto closes the file after the code in the 'with block' is executed.

Answer (score 0):

There are some possible improvements to be made. The first is using context manager for file handling - that is `with open(...)` - in case of exception, this will handle all the needed tasks for you.

Second, you have a small mistake in your dictionary assignment: the values are assigned using = operator, such as dict[key] = value.

```
y = {} 
with open("stuff.txt", "r") as infile: 
    for line in infile: 
        key, value = line.strip().split(':') 
        y[key] = (value) 

print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python3:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r', encoding = "utf-8") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        s=[] #converting strings to list
        for i in line.split(" "):
            s.append(i)
        d=dict(x.strip().split(":") for x in s) #dictionary comprehension: converting list to dictionary
        e={a: int(x) for a, x in d.items()} #dictionary comprehension: converting the dictionary values from string format to integer format
        print(e)
```